# Authentication with custom user model

Tags: python, django

I want to make login and registration for a custom user with only 5 fields: user name, name, password, linkedin id and mobile number.

I made registration successfully but I am stuck with login, I cannot authenticate my user.
Is there any way to authenticate my user, or how can I login?
Currently I am getting logged in by

```
user = Consultants.objects.get(Q(username= username) & Q(password= password))
```

But i want to make login by

```
user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
```

**Note:I don't want to use django default User Model For it**.
Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Consultants(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    linkedin_id=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False
    print "inside register view"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        consultant_form = ConsultantsForm(data=request.POST)
        if consultant_form.is_valid():
            consultant = consultant_form.save(commit=False)
            consultant.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print consultant_form.errors
    else:
         consultant_form = ConsultantsForm()
    return render_to_response(
            'register.html',
            {'consultant_form': consultant_form, 'registered': registered},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def login_user(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print type(username)
        try:
            user = Consultants.objects.get(Q(username= username) & Q(password= password))
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user.is_active:
                user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                login(request, user)
                a= request.user.username
                return HttpResponse("welcome......you are succesfuly log in")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your  account is disabled.")
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("INvalid User")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Note:I don't want to use django default User Model For it Please help
>   me in this. Thanks inadvance

Is your Consultants class inheriting from the base Django user class?

The authenticate() function is used to authenticate the base user model, you may not be setting a password for the user when they are created?

Another way to go about this would instead create a Profile model with all of these extra fields with a OneToOneField to the base user model, and authenticate though the Django ORM.

Comment: i don't want to use base class.i have a class Consultants with all field

Comment: Could you post your custom user model, signup form, and login view?

Comment: The reason you may be getting errors is because you are using django authenticate() where it expects a base auth User. If you with to continue with a custom login. You'll need to modify some middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends

Comment: I have none offhand but custom authentication is outlined in the docs I linked. Also it would be much easier (and much safer security wise) to use the base django user model for authenticate()

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to inheriting from django embedded user class, you can follow these steps:

- extend your custom user class from `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin`
- Assign and fill this config in `settings.py`:

  AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS_IN_FULL_QUALIFIED_NAME'  e.g.: 'your_app_name.Consultants'

Voila, you can use django default user crud, also authentication

Comment: can u give me link where i can see full implementation of this

Comment: sure , follow this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model